# Razor Pages Multiple CheckBoxes with Model Binding and At least one option must be checked Server/Client Validation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to have multiple checkboxes with validation where at least one is selected. Ideally, these checkboxes should bind to my page model.

I seem to continuously be running into different issues when I take different approaches. The following method, the client-side validation works, but then the model binding doesn't (and therefore server validation doesn't work). If I ignore client-side validation (remove javascript and the hidden asp-for="ProductLines" input), then I can get the server-side validation, and model binding to work. Ideally, I'd like to have model binding and client/server-side validation working.

I am surprised this isn't easily possible with razor pages. But, perhaps you can help? Otherwise, I may have better luck with a client-side and a server-side framework in the future. I am trying to avoid that because it seems overkill for simpler applications.

Checkbox Class:

```cs
    public class Checkbox
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Validation Attribute

```cs
    public class OneCheckboxMustBeChecked : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {

            var checkboxOptions = validationContext.ObjectInstance as List<Checkbox>;


            foreach (var option in checkboxOptions)
            {

                if (option.IsSelected)
                {

                    return ValidationResult.Success;

                }

            }

            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());

        }

        public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
        {
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
            MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-OneCheckboxMustBeChecked", GetErrorMessage());
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage()
        {
            return "A checkbox option must be selected";
        }

        private bool MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes, string key, string value)
        {
            if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return false;
            }

            attributes.Add(key, value);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Page Model (cshtml.cs):

```cs
        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Product Lines:")]
        [OneCheckboxMustBeChecked]
        public List<Checkbox> ProductLines { get; set; }
```

cshtml

```html
<div class="form-row row">

    <label class="col-form-label pt-0" asp-for="ProductLines"></label>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductLines" />

    <div id="ProductLineCheckBoxes">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductLines.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProductLines[i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProductLines[i].Name" />
                <input asp-for="@Model.ProductLines[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.ProductLines[i].IsSelected">
                    @Model.ProductLines[i].Name
                </label>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="ProductLines"></span>
</div>
```

Unobtrusive Jquery Validation

```js
//This is used to include hidden input tags into our unobtrusive jquery validation. 
//hidden input fields are not included in validation by default
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ""
});

$.validator.addMethod('OneCheckboxMustBeChecked',
    function(value, element) {

        var checked = $(element.nextElementSibling).find('input:checked');

        if (checked.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    });

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('OneCheckboxMustBeChecked',
    [],
    function (options) {
        options.rules['OneCheckboxMustBeChecked'] = [];
        options.messages['OneCheckboxMustBeChecked'] = options.message;
    });
```

Comment: I have checked your code on my side, but only the server side validation works well, the Client validation doesn't work. and it will show the ValidationUtil or MergeAttribute undefined error, whether I miss some reference, or you have overridden it, can you post the related import reference or method? Besides, as an alternative workaround, for the Client side validation, you could directly use JQuery to validate it, check [this article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-at-least-one-CheckBox-checked-selected-in-ASPNet-MVC-Razor.aspx).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Thanks for your response. I've added the MergeAttribute method. 

Yes, I could use JQuery to validate it. I was hoping that I could stick with the pattern that the Razor Page framework provides though. 

Since, that doesn't seem possible then custom JQuery might be the way to go.

Comment: I know I'm "bumping" this a little to late, and to ask a silly question. Why is there a need to use the hidden inputs on your form?

Answer (score 0):

> I seem to continuously be running into different issues when I take
> different approaches. The following method, the client-side validation
> works, but then the model binding doesn't (and therefore server
> validation doesn't work). If I ignore client-side validation (remove
> javascript and the hidden asp-for="ProductLines" input), then I can
> get the server-side validation, and model binding to work. Ideally,
> I'd like to have model binding and client/server-side validation
> working.

Based on your code, I have reproduced the problem. The issue is related the hidden filed:

`<input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductLines" />`

If adding the above code, it will add the client validation method to the hidden field, the Unobtrusive Jquery Validation method will execute. After validation success, if you set a debugger in the IsValid method, you can see that the parameter's value is null.

If removing the above code, since the web page doesn't contain the ProductLines element, the client validation attributes (such as "data-val" or "data-val-OneCheckboxMustBeChecked") are not added to the element. so the Unobtrusive Jquery Validation will not execute.

To solve this issue, in the OneCheckboxMustBeChecked method, after validation successful, remove the "ProductLines" hidden file.

```
$.validator.addMethod('OneCheckboxMustBeChecked',
    function(value, element) {

        var checked = $(element.nextElementSibling).find('input:checked');

        if (checked.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
            
        //remove the hidden files
        $("input[name='ProductLines']").remove();

        return true;

    });
```

Comment: That works, except if the form becomes invalid again. To fix that using this method, one would need to reattach the hidden input when an update occurred to the checkboxes. At that point, I feel like we've deviated further from the flow Microsoft and JQuery Validation has intended. Perhaps this solution is good enough though....